# change bibtex referencing

Tags: bibtex

How would I alter the bibtex referencing format in the references section from:

```
Author. Journal. volume. Year
```

to be:

```
Author. Year. Journal...
```

I cannot seem to find a command that changes the referencing format of such citations.

Comment: @Kate Which bibliography style (`.bst` file) do you use?

Comment: You can use `custom-bib` to create a new `.bst` producing the format you are after.

Comment: @Kate, joseph asked which bibliography style you use; this is the thing in braces in the command `\bibliographystyle{...}` in your latex file.  if you can tell us what those `...` are, in your file, we have a chance of finding something that matches it, but does “author-year” the way you want.

Comment: I use \bibliographystyle{plainnat}, the journal I am submitting into requires the references like the following: De Pol-Holz, R., O. Ulloa, L. Dezileau, J. Kaiser, F. Lamy, and D. Hebbeln. 2006. Melting of the patagonian ice sheet and deglacial perturbations of the nitrogen cycle in the eastern South Pacific. Geophys. Res. Lett. 33. So, we have authors, year, title, journal, issue, page numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not to hard to change `plainnat.bst` to place the year immediately after the author. Unfortunately, `plainnat.bst` does not format the authors as described, i.e., Author, I., I. Author ...  Again it is possible to modify the behaviour. The best solution is to use `custom-bib` to generate a new bibliography style.

You can use the following procedure

1. Open a terminal window
2. Run `latex makebst`
3. Follow the prompt and answer the questions in the prompt
4. Use `\bibliographystyle{<new>}` where `new` is the name of style selected in one of the first question of 3. above.